# Django raw query join many to many field

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

Models.py

```
class RestaurantKeyword(models.Model):
    keywords=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.keywords)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    web=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    lat =models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    lng =models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    avg_rating=models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    restaurant_type=models.ForeignKey(RestaurantType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    keywords=models.ManyToManyField(RestaurantKeyword,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

SQL raw query

```
SELECT id,name,( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(30.696627)) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(76.693764) ) + sin ( radians(30.696627) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance  FROM newbackend_restaurant
```

I have parameters like lat,lng, keyword. I need a query there i can use keywords to find my result.but  **keywords** is many to many fields.

#### DB schema

[image]

Comment: you want raw `sql` or django orm query?

Comment: I want query like 'SELECT id,name,( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(30.696627)) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(76.693764) ) + sin ( radians(30.696627) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance  AND keywords =burger FROM newbackend_restaurant'  if it could possible with Django query it will be good otherwise i will consider raw sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many relationships.

So based on your models i think the raw sql will looks like:

```
SELECT r.id,
       r.name,
       ( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(30.696627)) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(76.693764) ) + sin ( radians(30.696627) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM newbackend_restaurant r
    LEFT JOIN newbackend_restaurantrestaurantkeyword m2m
        ON m2m.restaurant_id = r.id
    LEFT JOIN newbackend_restaurantkeyword rk
        ON m2m.restaurantkeyword_id = rk.id
WHERE rk.keywords IN ('WORD', 'HELLO');
```

Hope you can fix the fields and table names your self.

Comment: Thanks 
This Query is working good with SQL command but in Django, it is showing error 
raise InvalidQuery('Raw query must include the primary key')

but when I use id there it shows error like django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id,name( 3959 * Acos(Cos(Radians(30.696627)) * Cos(Ra...

Comment: glad to help you. if all works fine you can and should accept the answer)